# Scrapy-Splash not rendering this site

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

Javascript not rendering at https://iwilltravelagain.com/latin-america-caribbean/?page=1
Can you tell me what could be the problem?

my settings:

```
SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050'


DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}

SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}

DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'

HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```

docker:

```
docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash --disable-private-mode
```

spider:

```
class MyspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider1'
    start_urls = ['https://iwilltravelagain.com/australia-new-zealand-asia/']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, args={'wait': 9.0})

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        print(response.body)
```

This works with other sites.

If you look through http://localhost:8050 - the page is also rendered without js.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just saw your post and I also struggle how to scraped this page. Even I simulate scroll the I still cant scraped the links.

Comment: When I used Selenium, I scraped all the data I need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Yeah, I also received data from this web site with usage of selenium.I just wanted to find out how to do this with splash